# Can I delete my own question?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, self-delete

I don't know if it is possible to delete my own question, however I would like to delete the question:

[Diference Behaviour Of Dispose Method Between Winforms And Textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645786/diference-behaviour-of-dispose-method-between-winforms-and-textboxes)

I get down-voted everyday because of my language barrier and sometimes people edit the question to make them reasonable, and in other cases I simply get down-voted.

How do I go about deleting this question?

Comment: You can [delete your own posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222), provided they satisfy some arbitrary criteria. You should be able to delete your post, since it is primarily downvoted and has no answers. There should be a "delete" option in the same line as "link" and "edit". If that doesn't work for whatever reason, I will flag it for moderator attention (since your reputation happens to be too low to flag, it seems), and they can delete it for you.

Comment: @Grace Note sir, thx

Comment: Me too -- the issue needs to be resolved :(

Comment: Sometimes I want to delete a question that I asked a while back just because I realize later that it's a dumb question and it makes me look stupid for asking.  But if there are already answers posted, I can't just delete it.

Comment: @mahesh Not sir, man. Grace is a female name

Comment: One of the BIG madness on this site. Questions asked SEVERAL YEARS ago, go on giving me bunches of downvotes, regularly. The question didn't receive any interesting answers, or even just one answer., and won't never, and I can't even delete my own question.. Madness.

Comment: @Quidam Did you read the post marked as duplicate? It explains the cases when you can't delete - if there's no answers and you've registered your account, you *should* be able to. If you're having trouble you could ask on that site's meta for help, or flag for moderator attention and request they delete/dissociate it for you.

Answer (score 16):

This is very late answer but I learned how to delete a post/question. I'm not sure if this is just an update to stackoverflow because this question is way back 2010. But bottom line, the answer is

**Yes you can delete your own post/question.**

Steps.

1. Open your account.
2. Click the question you want to delete in 'Questions' Table.
3. Click the delete button below your post/question.

(The post/question will not be deleted instantly because you have to wait for a day for reconsideration issues.)

I hope this helps future inquiry regarding with this matter.

Comment: What if the question already has an answer?

Comment: It can't be deleted if it has an approved answer.

Comment: No. It doesn't work.