# Getting an answer to a question with poor English in a Stack Overflow way

Tags: discussion, specific-question, languages, english

This is concerning my question [Difference in behaviours of Dispose method between winforms and textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645786/difference-in-behaviours-of-dispose-method-between-winforms-and-textboxes).

It is a helpful question, but I was not able to draft it well due to my poor English skills, and it was downvoted as a result. My intention in this Meta post is only to make newcomers to the site aware of this type of problem, which I faced and paid for. I don't want the same thing to happen to anyone else.

I know our community is brilliant, and I know its members can understand my poor comments and provide a good answer.

The name behind a question is not important, but it is important that the solution will prevent lots of people from making the mistake I made.

I want members of our community to draft an answer to my question and post it with our community's name.

Comment: I'm confused, but this is somehow related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/can-i-delete-my-own-question (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645786/diference-behaviour-of-dispose-method-between-winforms-and-textboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645786/diference-behaviour-of-dispose-method-between-winforms-and-textboxes) has been edited and undeleted, so other users can now view it if they have the same question or a helpful answer to post.

Are you asking that the question be turned into a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) post? You can do that yourself by editing it and checking the box just below the right corner of the edit window.